# Security and login - symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

i have an application based on symfony3. I did register and login from doccumentation.
It's my code in security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
       AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

providers:
    our_db_provider:
      entity:
          class: AppBundle:User
          property: username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

     main:
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
          form_login:
                  login_path: login
                  check_path: login
```

And on localhost is - FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 118:
The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\game\app/config\security.yml" does not contain valid YAML in C:\xampp\htdocs\game\app/config\security.yml (which is being imported from "C:\xampp\htdocs\game\app/config\config.yml").

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Another code is from my app is here - https://github.com/xrbartek/mirko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML is very particular on how indentation will change the structure of the configuration. You must keep the number of spaces consistent throughout the entire file.

I've taken a look at [your config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xrbartek/mirko/master/app/config/security.yml) and could see that by running it through a [YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) there were some issues.

I've corrected this to valid YAML below:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
            # app/config/security.yml
```

Comment: Now i have - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and localhost didn't work

Comment: Okay, but that is a separate question. You likely need to add `anonymous: ~` to your main firewall. This answer seems to have fixed your original question.